# Default expand the first panel in a panel group

Tags: javascript, css, panel

I'm trying to show the default first panel expanded and rest collapsed. The way I create them is by **_.each from Underscore.js**

```
<div class="panel_gp">
   <% _.each(model.models, function(modelData) { %>
     <div id="payment" class="panel-collapse collapse payment in" role="tabpanel"> <!--data inside panel--> </div>
   <% }); %>
</div>
```

Now if there are multiple records in my model, how do I keep a check to add **collapse in** class for only first panel? Please suggest.

---

#### Solved

Don't know if this is the right approach, but I found the solution:

```
<% if( model.models.indexOf(modelData) == 0) { %>in <%}%>
```

I added a check for index, if that has **index=0**, then only show **in**.

Comment: Please remove "Solved" from your title and question. You can post it as a proper answer and then mark it as "Accepted".